# буфер обмена с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

Есть вот такой код:

```
OpenClipboard(NULL);
cout << (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
EmptyClipboard();
CloseClipboard();
```

Программа выводит на экран содержимое буфера обмена(только текст), после чего очищает. Работает он хорошо, но проблема в том, что если буфер пустой программу крашит. 
Как узнать пустой ли буффер?
P.S. ошибка на 2 строке кода

Comment: Проверять значения, возвращаемые всеми функциями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *text = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
if (text) cout << text;
```